# How do I prove that delta - sinc function is the same as an (-1)^n times the sinc

Tags: dirac-delta

$$\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} \mbox{sinc} \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} \mbox{sinc} \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)$$

I tried to split it into two sequences: one for n even and one for n odd. I also tried to make use of the fact that  $sin(-\frac{n\pi}{2}) = (-1)^nsin(\frac{n\pi}{2}), \forall n \in \mathbb Z$

But so far I haven't managed to tie everything together. Here is a photo showing what I've tried so far. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZb0R.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please, could you read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Then what have you tried ?

Comment: @EDX  thank you for that. I have added a bit more context of what I have tried to do so far, to no avail.

Comment: And about which $\delta$ do you refer ? Is it zero centered delta ?

Comment: @EDX yes that is the one I mean

Comment: So you equality is an equality of distribution

Comment: @EDX please check the photo I just uploaded, maybe you can provide some guidance from there

Comment: Ok, I need to things to help you. The first is the rigorous definition of the $\delta$ you're using (there are several way of using a $\delta$ function, sometimes mathematicaly, sometimes with a more "physicists" approach (less rigourous). Furthermore there exists several notations used. So I need precision on this .Secondly the last equality isn't really true since $\dfrac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{\frac{n\pi}{2}} = sinc(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \neq sinc(\frac{n}{2} )$

Comment: I am using the engineering delta,I don't know if that helps. $ \delta (t) = 1 when t = 0 and \delta (t) = 0 when t \neq 0 $

Comment: So when $n \neq 0$ you can avoid delta. (Did you forget some $\pi$ ?

Comment: $
\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} sinc (\frac{n}{2}) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} sinc( \frac{n}{2})
$
Given that 
$
\sin{\frac{-n\pi}{2}} = (-1)^n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}
$
\\
$
\delta(n) - \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}} }{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$ = 
$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{-\pi n}{2}}}{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$
=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}}}{\frac{\pi n}{2}}
$
\\
=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \sin{\frac{n}{2}}
$
\\QED

Comment: The result is true (assuming that $sinc$ is defined here by $\sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$ and not $\sin(x)/x$ as usual. Its why I wasn't understanding your process.

Answer (score 1):

$
\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} sinc (\frac{n}{2}) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} sinc( \frac{n}{2})
$

Given that

$
\sin{\frac{-n\pi}{2}} = (-1)^n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}
$

$
\delta(n) - \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}} }{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$ =

## $
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{-\pi n}{2}}}{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$

$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}}}{\frac{\pi n}{2}}
$

=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \sin{\frac{n}{2}}
$

QED